# dpdk igb_uio driver not loading

Tags: module, driver, dpdk

I am trying to load the igb_uio driver into my kernel, and I am getting the error:

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module igb_uio.ko: Invalid module format

I have been sleuthing around and am finding generally the answer to this is usually a kernel version mismatch. I have checked my kernel version with uname -r and it matches the kernel version from modinfo igb_ui.ko

Any ideas what else might be going on?
Thanks,
Adam

Comment: @AdamMills common issue to `Invalid module format` is current Kernel version and Kernel source headers used for build `igb_uio.ko` is different. The right steps is to comapre by `modinfo [path to igb_uio]/igb_uio.ko | gerp vermagic` and `uname -r` as pointed out by stackinside. If its not same simply rebuild igb_uio will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I did sudo modprobe uio first. And the versions match using Vipin's method.

Comment: Hi @AdamMils are you still facing the issue? or is it resolved after rebuilding with right kernel headers?

Comment: HI @VipinVarghese No, thanks for getting back to me on that. I'm not sure what I did to fix it though *shrug

Comment: first good to hear you moved forward with regard to the issue. Second when you mention `No, thanks for getting back to me on that.`, I am going to assume what you meant to say is `I have been able to fix the issue (not sure how I did so). But thanks for asking.`

Comment: Hi All, I have gotten new NICs and am now faced with this same issue again. It seems that whenever the server restarts, the old i40e module gets loaded back into the kernel, and I get the same error message as the original question when trying to load igb_uio. Once again, the kernel versions match. Please help if you can.